# Poor quality with Wand convert function (Python)

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, wand

I'm using `Wand` to the first time with `Python` in order to convert a PDF file into a JPG file, then apply a good recognizion script with OpenCV.

But, when I converted `PDF -> JPG`, the quality is really ugly. Font is not clear and I don't find a way to do that perfectly.

**PDF file looks like :**

[image]

**The result given by my code looks like :**

[image]

**Finally my very little script (I just need to convert for the moment) :**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="/Users/test/Desktop/arrow.pdf") as img :
    img.save(filename="/Users/test/Desktop/PDF_to_JPG/arrow.jpg")
```

==> I miss an option ? I tried to change the size with `img.resize` option but none effect.

Thank you by advance

Comment: I didn't see this question, so I apologize for duplicate post.

Comment: It's all good, at least you found your solution, maybe you will have better luck next time on finding a solution before posting.